# Use of DllRegisterServer

Tags: com, dllregistration

`DllRegisterServer` is called, when Windows or OLE wants me to register my classes under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`. But I don't understand why this function has to be implemented, because when Windows/OLE can make calls to my DLL, then my classes are already registered with their CLSIDs and their path to the correct DLL. Can somebody tell me, what I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Is it not all about the registry entries? It allows e.g. `regsvr32.exe` to call in to your DLL and ask it to make the necessary entries in the registry.

Comment: So, when I made my registry entries manually (for test purposes), can I make an empty `DllRegisterServer` only returning `S_OK`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confounding the chicken and the egg.  In order for COM to help a client app to create objects and marshal calls, it needs to know where your COM server is located.  The client app just uses a number, a GUID, to tell COM what object it needs.  The mapping from a GUID to code in an executable file requires COM to know where that file is located first.  And, if necessary, how to marshal a call on an interface from one apartment to another.

It is registering the server that provides COM with that knowledge.  It writes keys in the registry that COM uses to find the file back.  Like the CLSID key, its InProcServer32 sub-key provides the path to the file.  Etcetera.  Or the manifest embedded in the client app if it chooses to use reg-free COM.

Observing this with SysInternals' Process Monitor can provide a lot of insight.  You'll see what DllRegisterServer() does and how a client app uses those keys.

Comment: Ok. I still don't get it. Let's say I've already made a registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{...}\InprocServer32` with its default value set to the path of my DLL. Then one of my objects is registered with its guid `{...}`. Did I make a task that is normally supposed to be done in `DllRegisterServer`? Becuase when I wouldn'd register my DLL manually, Windows/OLE don't know my DLL and cannot call `DllRegisterServer` on my DLL. So I though `DllRegisterServer` has another task.

Comment: @Cubinator73 `DllRegsiterServer` is called by `regsvr32.exe` and also directly or indirectly by any number of popular installers. This is the normal way for your DLL to register itself on installation and you should follow that convention.

Comment: Yes, DllRegisterServer() needs to do that.  It's not like you can't get it done another way, the odds for hard to diagnose mistakes when you make changes are however far too large.  Troubleshooting registration problems is never that much fun.

Comment: @HansPassant Ok, so my `DllRegisterServer` function should do what I've done manually. In order to make my DLL known to Windows/OLE when it isn't registered, but the registration routines are defined in `DllRegisterServer`, what do I have to do? Do I have to start `regsvr32.exe` via command line with my DLL as parameter?

Comment: You simply write the code to write the registry keys.  Stop thinking that you need to do anything with Regsvr32.exe, that's somebody else's job.  Whomever wants to register your server.  Could be an admin, could be an installer, could be a programmer that wants to test his program that uses your server.  This happens long after you've written and tested the code.

Comment: Ok. I think I understood this (finally). Thank you very much :)

Comment: For the record, authors of Windows Installer actually dissuade from using `DllRegisterServer` during installation, because it encapsulates (hides) what components are actually installed -- the registry keys and entries that `DllRegisterServer` will be adding on the host. The idea with Windows Installer, at least, was that the installation package author declared the components and WI would install them reliably and even when shared with other installations. With `regsvr32` and/or calling `DllRegisterServer` yourself, you need to do reference counting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For the peoples wondering about Title of Question

Example of COM object is Dynamic Context Menu ( which would be a DLL)

to register it-

First Make a Random GUID under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
Under That GUID make key named "InProcServer32"
set value of this key as full path of your DLL

This is called Manual Registration

people's with no knowledge of registry editing should also be able to register your dll too.

for that, you should write codes to make these GUIDS and InprocServer32 keys etc programatically Under the DLLRegisterServer() Function in your DLL

so that , people with no knoledge of registry editing will be able to type -

`regsvr32.exe "full path of your DLL"`

in command prompt for registring your DLL

when they type that command, regsvr32.exe will do nothing but call that DLLRegisterServer() in your DLL

and by calling this function, codes of writing registry keys such as making random GUID and InprocServer32 keys will be Executed ( which you have written )

so registry entries will be made and that is called Registration.

so , according to me regsvr32.exe was just created for the people who have less knowledge of how to edit registry.